# How to use uploaded artifacts (source map) on sentry

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sentry, minifiedjs

I managed to generate the source map of my minified javascript and uploaded to Sentry as an artifact e.g. 1.0.0.0

```
Sentry.init({
    dsn: "blah",
    beforeSend: (event, hint) => {
        const error = hint.originalException;
        if (error && error.message && (error.message.includes(' 401') || error.message.includes(' 404') || error.message.includes(' 500')))
          return null;
        else return event;
      },        
    environment: environment,
    release: "1.0.0.0"
```

When I do a production build and create some errors, I did see the readable stacktrace. But this only apply if I have the source map file on the same folder as my minified javascript. I guessed, Sentry aren't using my uploaded version of the source map.

If I removed my local copy of the source map, any errors will not have the stacktrace.

[image]

How do I make sentry to use the sourcemap which i have uploaded in sentry?